# Why is stability of D.E. defined on infinite interval?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I will cite the following definition (from an O.D.E textbook) of *the stability of a solution*:

**Definition.** Let $f:[0,\infty)\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and locally Lipschitz on $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. Then a solution $\phi:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ of the system:

$$
x'(t)=f(t,x(t)), \forall\ t\in [0,\infty)
$$

is called *stable* if for every $a\geq 0$ there exists $\mu(a)>0$ such that for every $\xi\in\Omega$ with $||\xi-\phi(a)||<\mu(a)$, the unique saturated solution $x$, of the problem

$$
\begin{cases} x'(t)=f(t,x(t)), \forall\ t\in [0,\infty) \\ x(a)=\xi\end{cases}
$$

is defined on $[a,+\infty)$ and for every $\epsilon>0$,there exists $\delta(\epsilon,a)\in (0,\mu(a)]$ such that for each $\xi\in\Omega$ with $||\xi-\phi(a)||<\delta(\epsilon,a)$ we have that:

$$||x(t)-\phi(t)||<\epsilon, \ \forall t\in [a,\infty).$$

**My question is: Why can't we define the stability of a solution on a bounded interval $[a,b]$?? Why we must consider only systems on $[a,+\infty)$?**

Comment: The answer is twofold. There is an ideological side of it and there is a technical side. Technically all solutions are stable when you are considering finite intervals of time. This is managed by a theorem about continuous dependence of solution on initial condition. The ideological side is that primarily people are interested in long-term evolution of systems: what happens, in what state system will be when you wait for time $T$, when $T$ is long enough and ideally $T \rightarrow \infty$? The usual definitiion of Lyapunov stability just captures the essence of this question.

Comment: @Evgeny: Why write such a good answer as a comment?

Comment: @HansLundmark To help somehow first and try not to forget to add useful details later :) And because my "answer" has caveat: there are plenty of papers that are focused on finite-time properties of dynamical systems. But I need to find few good references for this, and this can take quite long..